# is it possible to make onScroll event triggered for every pixel scrolled?

Tags: javascript

I am now trying to make a website feature just like changing some element opacity according to how much pixels is scrolled.

just like this func below:

```
function onScroll(){ 
    var scrolledDist = window.pageYOffset;
    var elementX = document.getElementById('elementX');
    elementX.setAttribute('style','opacity:'+(1-scrolledDist/1000));
}
```

This func does work, but sometimes it just doesn't work perfectly as I want. 
I found that if I scroll very fast, the onScroll event just doesn't trigger for every pixel scrolled(nor the last "1000th" pixel), which makes the opacity not 0 when I scroll to 1000.

I am wondering if there is any solution (or alternative) for this case.

Answer (score 1):

> Since scroll events can fire at a high rate, the event handler shouldn't execute computationally expensive operations such as DOM modifications. Instead, it is recommended to throttle the event using requestAnimationFrame(), setTimeout(), or a CustomEvent, as follows.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/scroll_event

I would suggest using `scroll` event listener. And use `Window.requestAnimationFrame()` to control your animations.

> The window.requestAnimationFrame() method tells the browser that you wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser calls a specified function to update an animation before the next repaint. The method takes a callback as an argument to be invoked before the repaint.

```
window.addEventListener('scroll', function(e) {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some events get triggered before the UI renders them. To make sure that those events are treated appropriately you should use a [`setTimeout(function(){/*code goes here*/}, 0)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout) call, so that the code inside will run as soon as the element gets scrolled.

Like so:

```
function onScroll(){
    setTimeout(function() {
        var scrolledDist = window.pageYOffset;
        var elementX = document.getElementById('elementX');
        elementX.setAttribute('style','opacity:'+(1-scrolledDist/1000));
    }, 0);
}
```